# Kdenlive crashes when clicking into timeline

Tags: kubuntu, crash, 16.10, kdenlive

I know that Kdenlive is very unstable, but it is still my favorite video editor under Linux. But now I am experiencing an issue, that makes editing impossible.

When I open Kdenlive and load a project (or create a new one and drop a clip into the timeline), Kdenlive immediately crashes.

This is the console output:

```
OpenGL vendor:  "NVIDIA Corporation"
OpenGL renderer:  "GeForce GT 630M/PCIe/SSE2"
OpenGL Threaded:  true
OpenGL ARG_SYNC:  true
OpenGL OpenGLES:  false
OpenGL vendor:  "NVIDIA Corporation"
OpenGL renderer:  "GeForce GT 630M/PCIe/SSE2"
OpenGL Threaded:  true
OpenGL ARG_SYNC:  true
OpenGL OpenGLES:  false
 // / processing file open
 // / processing file open: validate
Opening a document with version  0.95  /  0.95
 // / processing file validate ok
***********
FOUND GUIDES:  0 
**********
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 19785, resource id: 88080717, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 20043, resource id: 88080717, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
kdenlive: effect_chain.cpp:1746: void movit::EffectChain::render_to_fbo(GLuint, unsigned int, unsigned int): Assertion `status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE' failed.
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = kdenlive path = /usr/bin pid = 4973
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/kdenlive 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0
```

Is there a way to fix this? My version of Kdenlive is 16.08.2, it is installed on my Kubuntu 16.10 (amd64) laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It seems to be a bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=362877), that causes Kdenlive on computers with NVIDIA/movit plugins to crash.

Disabling GPU processing (`Settings → Configure Kdenlive → Playback → uncheck Use GPU processing (Movit library)`) fixed it. Because of that, I am not able to use GPU effects anymore, but the rest of Kdenlive works now.

Comment: That _bug_ is apparently unfixed to date.

Comment: …and still unfixed.

Comment: ...and still unfixed.

Comment: Enabled GPU once, ... now I cannot even disable the settings because It kicks me out just as I started